# TSQL Sort Union based on column not being returned

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, union

(Please note, I require a SQL Server 2005 solution)

I have a `UNION` query, where the first part returns multiple rows in a particular order, and the second part returns a single row which MUST the last row of the result set.

The easiest way I've found so far is to include an extra "sort" column, **BUT** I do not want this column to be returned with the data set.

Please note, this example has a single column, but the real query has many columns, built via dynamic query...

```
SELECT [TITLE],
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE] WHERE ...) AS [VALUE],
       0 AS [EXTRAORDER]
FROM dbo.[LOOKUPTABLE]
UNION
SELECT 'Total',
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE]),
       1 AS [EXTRAORDER]
ORDER BY [EXTRAORDER], [TITLE]
```

How can I creating this so that all the columns *excluding* `EXTRAORDER` are returned (preferably *without* manually listing all the desired columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless anybody can come up with a better solution, I have currently settled for the following...

(I was heading down the same route as SQLhint.com was in their answer.  Unfortunately their answer - at the time of writing - is still incorrect, and therefore I cannot upvote it. The `Total` row will still be ordered within the results of the main `SELECT`, rather than be "appended" to the end.)

Ideally I wanted a solution that *didn't* require the replication of all the columns required in the final data set.  Unfortunately this solution does NOT satisfy this requirement, but at least it works!

The solution was to use CTE...

```
; WITH [DATA] AS (
    SELECT [TITLE],
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE] WHERE ...) AS [VALUE],
        0 AS [EXTRAORDER]
    FROM dbo.[LOOKUPTABLE]
    UNION
    SELECT 'Total',
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE]),
        1
)
SELECT [TITLE], [VALUE]
FROM [DATA]
ORDER BY [EXTRAORDER], [TITLE]
```

Comment: I believe that all supported solutions to your requirements must follow this pattern.  That is, `UNION` first, with the sort column, then `SELECT` last (top/outermost), excluding the sort column from the column list, but still using it for `ORDER BY` in that final `SELECT`.  AFAIK, there's no other way to get a valid `ORDER BY` on a column that is not returned.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @RBarryYoung, I didn't think it would be possible to do it without listing all-but-one of the columns

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to return 2 result sets, but to respond strictly to your question:

```
SELECT [title], [value]
FROM
    (SELECT [TITLE],
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE] WHERE ...) AS [VALUE],
       0 AS [EXTRAORDER]
    FROM dbo.[LOOKUPTABLE]
    UNION
    SELECT 'Total',
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE]),
       1 AS [EXTRAORDER]) as A
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [title] = 'Total' THEN 'zzz' ELSE [title] END
```

Comment: Thanks, but `Total` will still be ordered within the results of the first `SELECT`

Comment: Sorry, but your update is invalid... you can't have `ORDER BY` within a subquery

Comment: I am heading down the same idea, but that will still result in `Total` being including with the `SELECT` information.  I have got it working (unfortunately by replicating ALL columns) by having the entire `UNION` *within* the CTE

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT [TITLE], [VALUE]
FROM (
    SELECT [TITLE],
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE] WHERE ...) AS [VALUE]
    FROM dbo.[LOOKUPTABLE]
    UNION
    SELECT 'Total',
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[OTHERTABLE])
) [DATA]
ORDER BY (case when [TITLE] = 'Total' then 1 else 0 end), [TITLE]
```

This removed the [EXTRAORDER] column but still orders based on the [TITLE] treating 'Total' as the last item.